# Problema asíncrono con la API Twitter y NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, twitter-api

Estoy haciendo un script que consulte el `'statuses/user_timeline'` de varias cuentas una detrás de otra y que al acabar siga el código, pero conforme entra con la API Twitter, `t.get('statuses/user_timeline')...` el código termina sin esperar los resultados.

Estoy usando generadores **co**, promesas **new Promise** pero se hace muy difícil.

```
module.exports = (data) => {
  co(function* () {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        yield t.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name:  data[i].nombre, since_id: data[i].last_tweet_id }, 
        (error, data) => {
            console.log(`Para: ${data[i].nombre} hay ${data.length} nue`introducir el código aquí`vos`)
        });
    }

  });
  return data;
}
```

Y el archivo desde donde se llama

```
const getAllAccounts = require('./functions/getAllAccounts');
const getNewTweets = require('./functions/getNewTweets');

module.exports = () => {
  getAllAccounts()
    .then((data) => {
        getNewTweets(data);
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

El último `then` llega antes que termine el anterior.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar este problema de sincronización?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español! He editado tu pregunta para modificar tu código. Hay dos tipos de herramientas para añadir código. Una que se puede ejecutar desde el sitio (html, javascript y css) y otra para otro código que no se ejecutará desde la web. En tu caso hay que usar la segunda ya que no se va a ejecutar el ejemplo. Por otra parte si pudieras enseñar la salida quizás quede más claro tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El último then llega antes que termine el anterior.

Para que un `then` espere a que termine el anterior debe retornar otra promesa. No se ve que tipo de dato retorna `getNewTweets` pero si retorna una Promesa, la solución seria:

```
 getAllAccounts()
    .then((data) => {
        return getNewTweets(data); // <-- fijate el return.
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Asi, el segundo `then`, se corresponde al `then` de `getNewTweets`.

Salu2